# What's wrong with my Answer SDP (WebRTC, iOS project)

Tags: ios, webrtc, sdp

Been trying to figure out what's wrong with my SDP answer sent from iOS application to custom server.  This server receives SDP answer fine from a web client that is able to receive the video feed.

iOS application receives the SDP offer from server same as Web client, however the SDP answer it sends back appears different.  I'm under the impression that something is wrong with the SDP answer and the connection is dropped prior to the ICE candidate exchange.

Any advice is appreciated!

EDIT: question answered.  I cannot close due to reputation limitations, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the incorrect SDP answer all the forward slashes are preceeded by backslashes. If this is the literal SDP answer sent you should remove the backslashes in the media line and rtpmap/extmap attribute lines.

Comment: correct, this looks like some JSON encoding/decoding goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks, the issue ended up being a JSON encoding issue.  However, now that I have exchanged SDP offer/answer and also ICE candidates, I still dont' have any video.  Any ideas?

Comment: That is a different problem, so you should start a new question. That means this question can be closed and it enlarges the chance that the new question will be answered.